# How to update props in Child component?

Tags: vue.js

When the computed data changed in parant component, the child component still use the old prop,which this props comes from parent component compunted data.

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I can only assume you're assigning the prop value to a data value during creation, ie `{ dataValue: this.propValue }` and you expect `dataValue` to update. This is not the case. You should always be able to rely on the prop value to be updated though

Answer (score 0):

I personally use watch for this.

```
Vue.component(
    data: function(){
        return{
            someProp:initProp
        }
    },
    ....
    props:['initProp'],
    ...
    watch:{
        initProp:function(val){
            someProp = val;
        }
    }
);
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ref="xxx"` when you create the child component and then set it via `this.refs.xxx.prop = "some value"` from the parent.

Example below:

```
<child ref="xxx" v-bind:prop1="10">
</child>

this.refs.xxx.prop1 = 15
```